# IF statement comparing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my IF statement, its kinda weird, cause every time my code loops in it, only SLOT1 is being called and displayed in my debugger, Why is it? Is there something wrong with my statement? Thanks.

```
    choiceSlot1 = TRUE;
    choiceSlot2 = TRUE;
    choiceSlot3 = TRUE;
    choiceSlot4 = TRUE;   

    if (slot1 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel1 currentItemView] tag] || twoSlot1 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || choiceSlot1 ) {

        NSLog(@"Slot1");
        choiceSlot1 = FALSE;

    } 
    else if (slot2 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel1 currentItemView] tag] || twoSlot2 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || choiceSlot2) {

        NSLog(@"Slot2");
        choiceSlot2 = FALSE;


    }
    else if (slot3 != [carousel1 indexOfItemViewOrSubview:carousel1.superview] || twoSlot3 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || choiceSlot3) {

        NSLog(@"Slot3");
        choiceSlot3 = FALSE;


    }
    else if (slot4 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel1 currentItemView] tag] || twoSlot4 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || choiceSlot4) {

        NSLog(@"Slot4");
        choiceSlot4 = FALSE;

    }
```

Comment: Well, you set choiceSlot1 to be true every time, so it always enters the first if.

Comment: `choiceSlot1` is always TRUE..

Comment: What should I do for the rest of the if statement to be called?

Comment: maybe try to set choiceSlots to false at first and then when you made changes you set them to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `else if` is only validated in case the first `if` statement is `false`.

Example:

```
if (true) 
{
    // Will be executed
} 
else if (true) 
{
    // Will not be executed
}

if (false) 
{
    // Will not be executed
} 
else if (true) 
{
    // Will be executed
}
```

Comment: What should I do for the rest of the if statement to be called?

Comment: Remove the `else` before the  `if`. In other words, make four separate `if` statements.

Comment: Yes, then in all of it is being logged.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy,

```
 if (slot1 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel1 currentItemView] tag] || twoSlot1 != [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel2 currentItemView] tag] || choiceSlot1 )
```

If choiceSlot1 is TRUE, then the first statement is always going to be true (with an OR, its true if one of the elements is true).

When the first statement is true, then the rest of the else/if are not called!